# DOM operation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

```
<div id="selector">
        <div class="button" id="1">hide
        </div>
        <div class="button" id="2">hide
            <p>Im out of selector scope</p>
        </div>
        <div class="button" id="3">hide
        </div>
        <div class="button" id="4">hide
        </div>
  </div>  

<script>
 function solve() { 
   $('#selector').on("click", ".button", function () {
    if (($(this).text()) === 'hide') {
       $(this).first().text('show');
       $(this).next().css("display", "none");
    } else {
       $(this).first().text('hide');
       $(this).next().css("display", "");
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Hello I'm new to jquery and I need help.The function is not working the way I want when I use it on the middle div which contains more nodes they're erased after the hide/show and I want to keep them. I don't wanna use .hide()/.show() or .toggle()
I don't know how to select the text node and change only the text not all the content of the div. The text must stay like this not in a span or any other tag
This isnt all the code and how its attached its working but aint properly

Comment: This would be *a lot* easier and more reliable if you could actually change the markup, even slightly.  Is there really a compelling reason why you can't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with the attempt so far:

- The "text" doesn't *equal* hide or show in reasonable cases, but it does *contain* it.
- Once you replace the text, you've clobbered that child element.  You need to retain the HTML and just replace one piece of its text.
- `next()` targets the neighboring element, not child elements.

Addressing these, I've come up with [this](https://jsfiddle.net/eu23xe9b/1/):

```
$('#selector').on("click", ".button", function () {
    if (($(this).text().includes('hide'))) {
        $(this).first().html($(this).first().html().replace('hide', 'show'));
        $(this).children().css("display", "none");
    } else {
        $(this).first().html($(this).first().html().replace('show', 'hide'));
        $(this).children().css("display", "");
    }
});
```

It's not super robust, because any other "show" or "hide" text within the elements is going to cause problems.  But it does "work" for the example markup given.  You *really* probably want to change the markup in some way.  Identifying things by string comparison is just an inexact science.  Separating target elements into actual HTML elements will make this much easier and more reliable.

Comment: its just with exercises purpose and wont be applyed anywhere as the way it is. Thanks for your help. I've tried a lot of things and of course with toggle or the ready show()/hide() is much easier but that's not the point